# After detecting objects in a video stream, I want to crop and save these objects

Tags: tensorflow, crop, object-detection

I had detected objects in a video and i want to crop these objects. I tried tensorflow APIs but none of them worked with me. When trying tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
    image,
    offset_height,
    offset_width,
    target_height,
    target_width
) 
it tells me that offset_height didn't defined.

So, i need a guide into how to crop object from an image using tensorflow.

Comment: Did you check whether offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width is not null or not? sometimes it does not find any object and that's why it cannot crop

Comment: Please, could you tell me how to check that??

Comment: Just simply use if condition and check if you have data or not. If you have try to go further. If you still encounter an error try to add code snippet and error so I can get more idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :
tf.image.crop_and_resize(image,boxes,box_ind,crop_size,method='bilinear',extrapolation_value=0,name=None)

For example:

```
    #bounding box coordinates
    ymin =boxes[0][0][0]
    xmin =boxes[0][0][1]
    ymax =boxes[0][0][2]
    xmax =boxes[0][0][3]
    test = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image=frame_expanded/255,
           boxes=[[ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax]],
           box_ind=[0],
           crop_size=[100,100])
```

Worked for me!

or if you want to use tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(...) try this:

```
    #bounding box coordinates
    ymin =boxes[0][0][0]
    xmin =boxes[0][0][1]
    ymax =boxes[0][0][2]
    xmax =boxes[0][0][3]
    #image_size
    (im_width,im_height) = image.size
    (xminn, xmaxx, yminn, ymaxx) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,   ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
    test=tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(frame,int(yminn), int(xminn), int(ymaxx-yminn), int(xmaxx-xminn))
```